# Bad K-means with Gradient Descent using TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, cluster-analysis, k-means, gradient-descent

Currently learning TensorFlow I'm working to implement kmeans clustering using TensorFlow. I am following a tutorial on TensorFlow which [first introduce kmeans](http://learningtensorflow.com/lesson6/) then [introduce Gradient Descent Optimization](http://learningtensorflow.com/lesson7/)

We first generate samples

```
def create_samples(n_clusters, n_samples_per_cluster, n_features, embiggen_factor, seed):
    np.random.seed(seed)
    slices = []
    centroids = []
    # Create samples for each cluster
    for i in range(n_clusters):
        samples = tf.random_normal((n_samples_per_cluster, n_features),
                               mean=0.0, stddev=5.0, dtype=tf.float32, seed=seed, name="cluster_{}".format(i))
        current_centroid = (np.random.random((1, n_features)) * embiggen_factor) - (embiggen_factor/2)
        centroids.append(current_centroid)
        samples += current_centroid
        slices.append(samples)
    # Create a big "samples" dataset
    samples = tf.concat(0, slices, name='samples')
    centroids = tf.concat(0, centroids, name='centroids')
    return centroids, samples
```

then define 2 function `assign` & `update` (+ euclidian distance) as usual

```
def assign(data, centroids):

    # Explanations here: http://learningtensorflow.com/lesson6/
    expanded_vectors = tf.expand_dims(samples, 0)
    expanded_centroids = tf.expand_dims(centroids, 1)

    # nice trick here: use 'sub' "pairwisely" (thats why we just used "expand")
    # 
    distances = tf.reduce_sum( tf.square(
               tf.sub(expanded_vectors, expanded_centroids)), 2)
    mins = tf.argmin(distances, 0)
    nearest_indices = mins
    return nearest_indices

def update(data, nearest_indices, n_clusters):

    # Updates the centroid to be the mean of all samples associated with it.
    nearest_indices = tf.to_int32(nearest_indices)
    partitions = tf.dynamic_partition(samples, nearest_indices, n_clusters)
    new_centroids = tf.concat(0, [tf.expand_dims(tf.reduce_mean(partition, 0), 0) for partition in partitions])
    return new_centroids

def euclidian_distance(x, y):
    sqd = tf.squared_difference(tf.cast(x, "float32"),tf.cast(y, "float32"))
    sumsqd = tf.reduce_sum(sqd)
    sqrtsumsqd = tf.sqrt(sumsqd)

    return sqrtsumsqd
```

Then define the TensorFlow model to run:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

nclusters = 3
nsamplespercluster = 500
nfeatures = 2
embiggenfactor = 70
seed = 700



np.random.seed(seed)
ocentroids, samples = create_samples(nclusters, nsamplespercluster, nfeatures, embiggenfactor, seed)

X = tf.placeholder("float32", [nclusters*nsamplespercluster, 2])

# chosing random sample points as initial centroids. 
centroids = tf.Variable([samples[i] for i in np.random.choice(range(nclusters*nsamplespercluster), nclusters)])#, [10.,10.]])
                         mean=0.0, stddev=150, dtype=tf.float32, seed=seed))


nearest_indices = assign(X, centroids)
new_centroids = update(X, nearest_indices, nclusters)

# Our error is defined as the square of the differences between centroid
error = euclidian_distance(centroids, new_centroids)

# The Gradient Descent Optimizer
train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(error)


model = tf.initialize_all_variables()

with tf.Session() as session:
    data = session.run(samples)
    session.run(model)
    epsilon =  0.08
    err = float("inf")
    count = 0
    while err > epsilon:
        _, err = session.run([train_op, error], {X: data})
        print(err)
        clustering = session.run(nearest_indices)
        centers = session.run(centroids)


        count += 1

        # Plot each 100 iteration to see progress
        if (count % 100) == 0:
            print(count)
            plt.figure()
            plt.scatter(data[:,0], data[:,1], c=clustering)
            plt.scatter(centers[:,0], centers[:,1], s=300, c="orange", marker="x", linewidth=5)


print("%d iterations" % count)

plt.figure()
plt.scatter(data[:,0], data[:,1], c=clustering)
plt.scatter(centers[:,0], centers[:,1], s=300, c="orange", marker="x", linewidth=5)
```

This is actually working (running) but the result is decieving:
[image]

After around 1600 iteration the result is so bad. I dont even figure out how some points can be "lost" (= clustered as a color they are so away from). To my mind kmeans can converge rlly fast on such case. Here it is not even converging to a good solution. Is it due to Gradient Descent? (don't see how could it be but...)

Thanks for advices!

pltrdy

Comment: It's hard to know what's wrong without debugging your code, but it looks to me like the code that computes `nearest_indices` must have some sort of bug --- that much is clear from the plot. I doubt that the gradient descent part of the algorithm is related. Perhaps try writing some tests for that algorithm in isolation?